# Combining Multiple Faces

Tags: uv, vertices, faces

Recently I've been able to optimize my meshes neatly and easily UV Unwrap them. But as I work with voxels, you can see a large amount of faces are created. Is there an easy way I can select all the faces on a plane and merge them?

[image: Original Mesh]

I do understand that this can be done by selecting the faces by hand then pressing F. I was just looking for an automatic way of doing these meshes.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to select all and X > Limited Dissolve?

Comment: Not yet, but I decided to try that just now. You're a life saver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Limited Dissolve*. You can set the angle in the *Operator* box (panel at the bottom left of your 3D view).